# Differential Geometry Wedge Products

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

1) If $f^1∧f^2...f^k$ are real valued smooth functions, then show that
$$d(df^1∧df^2...df^k)=0$$

2) If $f^1∧...∧f^k : U⊂R^n→R$  are smooth functions, then
$$df^1∧df^2...df^k=\displaystyle \sum_{i_1<...<i_k}\left|\frac{\partial(f^1,...,f^k)}{\partial(x^{i_1},...,x^{i_k})}\right|dx^{i_1}∧...∧dx^{i_k}$$
where $$\left|\frac{\partial(f^1,...,f^k)}{\partial(x^{i_1},...,x^{i_k})}\right|$$is  the Jacobian determinant.

In 1), the wedge product of functions gives me a square matrix which it's left diagonal is zero. The part I'm missing that I differentiate it,why it becomes a zero matrix.

Sadly I have no opinion  in 2).

Comment: For 1, use the Leibniz rule for wedge products and that $d^2=0$.

Comment: 2 can be proved by induction on $k$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally I proved both of them.